# Ubuntu Touch/Phone Nexus 4 - 'No Data Sources Available'

Tags: system-installation, ubuntu-touch, nexus-4

Brand new Nexus 4, purchased to install and test out Ubuntu Touch OS.

Successfully flashed the image through adb and following the official instructions here:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Install

Ubuntu boots on the Nexus 4 without problems and can connect to Wifi, can be accessed via ssh as well, but on the phone's home/splash screen I have the message in the centre of the circle of dots saying:

"No data sources available"

What does that mean? Did I do something wrong?

Comment: This is the normal startup behaviour. *Did you read the other Wiki pages?* eg. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Nexus7/UsingTheDevice

Comment: @david6 Thank you, you are right, it was fine and I was being paranoid/not understanding what was meant by data sources with the OS Preview.

Comment: Changed to answer, for you.

Comment: I have provided an anwser below that sound logic for today (14.10)

Comment: Thanks @cm-t - marked as answered since it is actually more accurate answer and will be better for others who might find the question currently/in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This message "No data sources available" means you didn't started to use the phone, and its apps.

Try to send/receive some sms or phone call, listen songs, take pictures, drink water... 
(using the apps)

Then you will see some dots in orange and purple taking more and more size over the days.

**What is it?**

The main circle is the **month**.

White dot with the arrow is **today**.

Other **orange and purple circle** are the number of time you were active in the activity described by the sentence you can read in the middle.

The biggest circle will be your biggest time active in that activity *(if it was 42 hours, minutes, pound, number of sms, music or any units, then 42 scale for the biggest circle, and other will be between 0 and 42)*

Every day in a month, "today" will replace the last size (value) of the last circle with the current.

If you **double tap inside the big circle** (where stand the sentence) you will be able to change a source (sms, pics, call, ...).

If after using some apps you still having the message "No data sources available", please add your +1 (the link "Does this bug affect you? ") in this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity8/+bug/1286276

Answer (score 2):

### This is the normal startup behaviour.

*Did you read the other Wiki pages?*

eg. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Nexus7/UsingTheDevice

Comment: This wiki page is noted as "This project is no longer maintained. You might be interested in Ubuntu Touch though." because it is about nexus7 (and not 4) and not "ubuntu touch" (ubuntu with unity8). I added my awnser that explain what it is, and what to do if nothing is changing.